# React Format Date, reconvert into MM/DD/YYYY Format

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React, and receiving the following data in Typescript. I want to display date in this format. mm/dd/yyyy,

```
export type Payment = {
  paymentId: number;
  paymentDate: Date;
} 

Data looks like this example: 2022-02-11T20:00:00.000Z
```

I cannot do this, as it gives error: `date .toISOString is not a function`

```
{payment.paymentDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10)}
```

I have to reconvert into Date again to show. All my dates are valid in checking data, so why do I need to reconvert again?

```
{new Date(payment.paymentDate).toISOString().substring(0, 10)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your `paymentDate` isn't really a JavaScript `Date`, but a `string.

`string` doesn't have `toIsoString` method

TypeScript is only a build time tool, it can't enforce data type.

I would use a library like date-fns for example, but other than that, you can use [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: hi Konrad, just learning that, how come my Typescript isn't enforcing data coming through api, and how would I convert to mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: TypeScript is only a build time tool, it can't enforce data type

Comment: ok I see, how would I convert to date then? is this correct? new Date(payment.paymentDate).toISOString().substring(0, 10)

Comment: I would use a library like `date-fns` for example, but other than that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: You can also check `zod` for data validation